# google apps script get string values of cell with formula

Tags: string, google-apps-script

Anyone know of a way to get the plain text value of a cell that is outputted with a formula using google apps scripts? e.g. I have FName and LName columns. I've concatenated the columns into FullName. I would like to copy the FullName column values to another column. I just want to copy the string value of FullName not the formula it was outputted with.

Comment: What are you doing now that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [copyTo method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options) with the option `contentsOnly: true`. Its effect is equivalent to Ctrl-C followed by Ctrl-Shift-V (paste values) in the spreadsheet interface. Example:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("F:F"); 
var target = sheet.getRange("J:J");
range.copyTo(target, {contentsOnly: true});
```

(Another way is to use `getValues` followed by `setValues`, but `copyTo` does both things at once.)

Comment: If you are needing to store the displayed value in a variable you can use range.getDisplayValue()